# Homepage (domain) that redirects user toward two subdomains based on his/her preferred language

Tags: redirect

I want to have a domain (e.g. website.com) that upon reaching that, the user decides the language he wants to continue. I planned for two languages. SEO doesn't matter for me. so what do you recommend? two subdomains? or two folders? in cPanel?
I haven't any programming skill, so should I install WordPress for all three sections?

Comment: Are the sites going to be identical but just in different languages, or independent sites?

Comment: not identical but similar. two similar subdomains with different languages.